# Accessing instance values from a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Car {
    carDetails = {
        carID : 0,
        carMake : '',
        carModel : '',
        carYearMade : '',
        carEngineDetails : {
            engineCylinders : 0,
            engineCC : 0,
            engineHP : 0 
        }
    };

    constructor(cMake, cModel, eCylinders, eCC, eHP) {
        this.carDetails.carMake = cMake;
        this.carDetails.carModel = cModel;
        this.carDetails.carEngineDetails.engineCylinders = eCylinders;
        this.carDetails.carEngineDetails.engineCC = eCC;
        this.carDetails.carEngineDetails.engineHP = eHP;
        ++this.carDetails.carID;
    }
}
```

Mechanic class is below:

```
class Mechanic {
    mechanicDetails = {
        mechanicName : '',
        mechanicAge : '',
        mechanicLocation : ''
    };

    constructor(mName, mAge, mLocation) {
        this.mechanicDetails.mechanicName = mName;
        this.mechanicDetails.mechanicAge = mAge;
        this.mechanicDetails.mechanicLocation = mLocation;
    }

    carRepair(carID, mName){
        //code validate carID
    }
}
```

Just recently started learning JS
Apologies if my question doesn't make any sense, but what I ma trying to do is, make sure the car exist before any action takes place

```
carRepair(carID, mName){
    //code validate carID
}
```

but can not figure out how to access the values of a object of a class

```
const car1 = new Car('Volvo', 'C60', 6, 3, 150)
```

How to validate the carID from the Mechanic class?

Comment: The properties are private. Why did you make them private when you want to access them? You could add getters.

Comment: let say i remove the #. What should be the code to check if the carID exist?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This should be explained by every basic tutorial out book

Comment: Unless the OP somewhere (preferably at construction time or immediately after) keeps track of each created `Car` instance, there is no chance of implementing such a check for `carRepair` which in addition should change from being a prototypal `Mechanic` to being a prototypal `Car` method.

Comment: I did try to find answer in here and tutorials, but I either can not formulate the question correctly to find similar posts or there are no similar posts.

Comment: You could `carID === car1.carDetails.carID`

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for suggestions. This is how I tried to do what i planned. Not sure if that is the best way. Please let me know.

```
Car class:

    class Car {

    static #carDatabase =[];
    static #carCount = 0;


    #carDetails = {

        carID : 0,
        carMake : '',
        carModel : '',
        carEngineDetails : {
            engineCylinders : 0,
            engineCC : 0,
            engineHP : 0 
        }

    };

    constructor(cMake, cModel, eCylinders, eCC, eHP) {
        this.#carDetails.carID = ++Car.#carCount;
        this.#carDetails.carMake = cMake;
        this.#carDetails.carModel = cModel;
        this.#carDetails.carEngineDetails.engineCylinders = eCylinders;
        this.#carDetails.carEngineDetails.engineCC = eCC;
        this.#carDetails.carEngineDetails.engineHP = eHP;
        Car.#carDatabase.push(this.#carDetails);
        console.log(`Car is registered. ID: ${this.#carDetails.carID}`);

    }

   static selectCarFromDB(carId){
    const carSelect  = Car.#carDatabase.find(car => car.carID === carId);
    return carSelect;
   }


}
module.exports = Car;
```

and the Mechanic Class:

```
    const Car = require("./Car");

class Mechanic {

    

    #mechanicDetails = {
        mechanicName : '',
        mechanicAge : '',
        mechanicLocation : ''
    };

    constructor(mName, mAge, mLocation) {
        this.#mechanicDetails.mechanicName = mName;
        this.#mechanicDetails.mechanicAge = mAge;
        this.#mechanicDetails.mechanicLocation = mLocation;
 
    }

    carRepair(carID){
        const carSelect = Car.selectCarFromDB(carID);
        console.log(`${carSelect.carMake}  is being repaired by 
         ${this.#mechanicDetails.mechanicName}..`); 
    }





      }

    module.exports = Mechanic;
```

and it seems to work with

```
const car1 = new Car('Jeep','Trackhawk' , 6, 600, 700);
const car2 = new Car('Volvo','C80' , 6, 300, 320);
const car3 = new Car('Toyota','Camry', 4 , 420, 300);
const mech1 = new Mechanic('John', 36, 'Owatonna, MN');

mech1.carRepair(1);
```

Comment: I know it is not the best way to do it. Instead of voting down, I would appreciate if you could explain what is the best way to do it.